# How to get a specific limit of item in an array using swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

As title says (not sure about my english). I am new to swift language.

I am currently working in a swift app where a a user pick the correct answer in a randomize  questions.

I am using gameplaykit for randomizing

```
var questions = ["question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question5"]// my question array

func askQuestion(){
        countries = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: countries) as! [String]//to randomize
...
}
```

So my app are working fine in randomizing all the question1...questionN repeateadly but what i want is to have a limit i.e. only 5 questions will be given.

I searched but found "getting the specific index of an array", not what i'm looking for.
Could you help me how to achieve this? or Is my approach right?
Thanks

Comment: So your question is "how to get the first 5 elements of an array"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefix(n) on an array to get the first n elements, such as:

```
countries = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: countries).prefix(3) as! [String]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 func askQuestion() {
    countries = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: countries) as! [String]

//After randomize your array use prefix method -

 let limit = 5
 let updatedCountries = Array(countries.prefix(limit)) // Use this `updatedCountries` array to display in UI.

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get first N numbers of elements using Prefix. Here is an example

```
 let n = 5 // could be any number of your choice 
 let firstNNumbers = questions.prefix(n)
```